# How do I remove all numbers from a string except date and time using regex on Python?

Tags: python, regex, date, parsing

I have multiple strings of text of the following type:

`04/12/2010 16:12:12  - 2763 /=CSE 27288-HAND CONTROL NOT WORKING ETA 1400-1500 /=`

I want to remove all numbers from this text and only retain the date and alpha text

expected output:
`04/12/2010 16:12:12  -  /=CSE -HAND CONTROL NOT WORKING ETA - /=`

Can anyone guide me and help with a regex expression for the same?
I am working on python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will run this regex on a part of the string **given the format is constant**:

```py
import re
text = "04/12/2010 16:12:12  - 2763 /=CSE 27288-HAND CONTROL NOT WORKING ETA 1400-1500 /="
text = text[0:20] + re.sub(r'-?\s?[0-9]+[0-9-]*', ' -', text[20:])
print(text)
```

Basically it takes the data and time and concatenates the regex substitution result to it.

```
04/12/2010 16:12:12   - /=CSE -HAND CONTROL NOT WORKING ETA - /=
```

Note: You can replace the double-space on the first match afterwords but i don't think it really affects much.